# What is the best way to utilize the open() javascript function when working with mysql databases?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am working to create a shorter `URI` for my photos and pdf docs which I am pulling from a `mysql database`. They are stored as `blobs`.

When I extract my photos or `pdfs` as `blobs` from my database, I encode them in `base64`. This creates a ridiculously long `img src`. I want to shorten this by using `AJAX`. The problem I am having is that I am not sure what to set as my link in the `open()` function in javascript.

1. The link appears without the URI conversion

`<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,**65,648-character-blob**" class="photo" id="image" alt="">`

2. The link after the URI conversion.

`<img src="blob:http://www.somedomain.com/7ab702ba-ba1f-4cac-9bc7-6f15d91ba2c3" class="photo" id="image" alt="">`

The specific code is below with

`xhr.open("GET", "", true);`

The beginning of my code so far is below:

```
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //console.log(xhr.readyState);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

        // check readyState and status
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
        console.log(responseText);
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "what should be here?", true);

    xhr.send();
```

I console.log document, I can see all of my photo links as shown in example #1 above.

I console.log xhr.responseText, I see only the first link in base64. I need to extract that img src information.

I found several videos to perform this transition. However, none of the deal with results from a database. They all reference a file directly.

Comment: so what is the purpose then? It makes little sense to use a blob url if you are making an http request to fetch it.

Comment: how did you retrieve the blob data to begin with? the answer to this really is on the server side. the server can serve images from the database based on an id in the URL, if you code it that way. then depending on how you code it to serve those images, would answer your question above.

Comment: @dphendricks I pull the blob from mysql via a pdo. I have tried encoding it both in the html and before I echo it out to my page as a link. The encoding works fine. The images will display, but they link is ridiculous. The purpose is to shorten the link. When I pull larger pdf files, the uri is ridiculously long. The browser will not display it.

Comment: A blob URL refers to data in the browser's memory, not on the server. It doesn't make sense to get it with AJAX.

Comment: @barmar this is the process to which I am referring. This process works if they image is in a file. When you set up the open() function, you point the link to a file. I am trying to adapt this concept to a blob from my database rather than a file. Does that make sense? https://synaptiklabs.com/posts/what-is-a-blob-uri/

Comment: Look at his next post: https://synaptiklabs.com/posts/creating-blobs-and-blob-uris/

Comment: @Barmar yes, I downloaded the code for that from git hub. The problem is that it only references the image directly as a file not as a db object open("GET", "./image.jpg") that is the piece I am missing. Because my blobs are in a database and not in a file, I am trying to figure out how to pull in the data which I am sending to the webpage. What would replace image.jpg? How would I reference my image?

Comment: As far as the client is concerned, it makes no difference. You can write a PHP script that extracts the image from the DB, then just does `echo $row['image'];`

Comment: Just change the URL to the URL of the script that does this.

Comment: I dont follow that logic. Can you explain?

Comment: If that's not the issue, then I think it's just `xhr.open("blob:http://www.somedomain.com/7ab702ba-ba1f-4cac-9bc7-6f15d91ba2c3")`

Comment: Ok, that link is end result of the function. There is no input into the function to create that link. I am not storing my files in a folder and then referencing the location of the files to generate that link. I am trying to figure out how to utilize this function for files being loaded from a database. I don't think you understand what I am asking.That link is an example.